# How to solve a differential equation involving $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation (1) : $ \frac{d}{dt} V(t)+ \frac{1}{C} V(t) = \frac{B}{C} \sin{(\omega t)} $. (where $B$,$C$ and $\omega$ are constants)

I approached this equation by first solving the homogeneous part for which I get the following solution :

$V_{c}(t) = K e^{\frac{-t}{C}}$ (where $K$ is a constant).

I need to find a particular solution of the type: $V(t) = A \cos{(\omega t + \phi)}$.

From (1), I get the following equation (2): $- A \omega \sin{(\omega t + \phi )} + \frac{1}{C} A \cos{(\omega t + \phi)} = \frac{B}{C} \sin{(\omega t)}$.

My question is; how to solve this (2) equation for $\phi$ and $\frac{B}{C}$ ?

Comment: Hint $cos(x-\pi/2)=sin(x)$

Comment: Equivalently, it may be easier to look for a particular solution of shape $p\cos(\omega t)+q\sin(\omega t)$.

Comment: (2) is not a differential equation. One way to approach (2) is to evaluate it at cleverly selected values of $t$, such as $t=-\phi/\omega$, $t=((\pi/2)-\phi)/\omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\totald{\bracks{{\rm V}\pars{t}\expo{t/C}}}{t}={B \over C}\,\expo{t/C}\sin\pars{\omega t}\quad\imp\quad
{\rm V}\pars{t}\expo{t/C} = {B \over C}\,\int\expo{t/C}\sin\pars{\omega t}\,\dd t + A
$$
where $A$ is a constant.

> \begin{align}
> {\rm V}\pars{t}& = A\expo{-t/C} +
> {B \over C}\,\expo{-t/C}\Im\int\expo{\pars{1/C + \ic\omega}t}\,\dd t
> =A\expo{-t/C} +
> {B \over C}\,\expo{-t/C}
> \Im\bracks{\expo{\pars{1/C + \ic\omega}t} \over 1/C + \ic\omega}
> \\[3mm]&=A\expo{-t/C} +
> {B \over C}\,
> \Im\bracks{\expo{\ic\omega t}\pars{C^{-1} - \ic\omega} \over\omega^{2} + C^{-2}}
> =
> A\expo{-t/C} +
> {B \over C}\,
> {C^{-1}\sin\pars{\omega t} - \omega\cos\pars{\omega t} \over\omega^{2} + C^{-2}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
{\rm V}\pars{t}=A\expo{-t/C}
+B\,{\sin\pars{\omega t} - \pars{\omega C}\cos\pars{\omega t}
\over \pars{\omega C}^{2} + 1}}
$$

> $A$ is determined by an initial condition.